# Why does CASE evalulate the ELSE clause?

Tags: oracle, null, oracle11g, case

Oracle 11g: Consider the following two CASE Statements

**SEARCHED CASE**

```
with null_table as (select null as null_set from dual )
select 
     case 
     when (null_set is null) then 'NULL INDEED'
     else 'NOTNULL?'
     end as AM_I_NULL_OR_NOT   
from null_table
```

**SIMPLE CASE**

```
with null_table as (select null as null_set from dual )
select 
     case null_set
     when  (null) then 'NULL INDEED'
     else 'NOTNULL?'
     end as AM_I_NULL_OR_NOT   
from null_table
```

The Searched CASE evaluates **null_set** as expected, yet, Simple CASE appears not to do so.

Questions: 
How do I perform a Simple CASE evaluation on **null_set** ?

Why does the Simple CASE evaluate as it does?

Comment: Nothing is equal to null (even null itself). The second version's first when can never trigger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle, null cannot be compared against using the `=` operator.

For example:

```
select * from dual where null = null; -- No result
select * from dual where 1 = 1; -- gives a result
```

So what you can do is use `NVL` to replace null by another value :

```
with null_table as (select null as null_set from dual )
select 
     case nvl(null_set,'X')
     when  'X' then 'NULL INDEED'
     else 'NOTNULL?'
     end as AM_I_NULL_OR_NOT   
from null_table
```

(make sure your field can never be equal to the value, X in the example.)

Comment: Strangely though, you CAN use the old Oracle decode function and it will match on null e.g. decode (null, null, 'IT IS NULL', 'IT IS NOT NULL') will return 'IT IS NULL'.

Comment: @LordPeter, maybe this is why `decode` is considered - many times - as *null-related function* such as `nvl` and `nvl2` (http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/null-related-functions.php)